# The following packages have unmet dependencies "openjdk-8-jdk" when installing google-cloud-sdk-pubsub-emulator on Kali Linux

Tags: java-8, java-11, google-cloud-sdk

I want to install the package "google-cloud-sdk-pubsub-emulator" on Kali Linux.

However, the error logs happen `The following packages have unmet dependencies` and `Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-pubsub-emulator
[sudo] password for cybersec-kali: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-cloud-sdk-pubsub-emulator : Depends: openjdk-8-jdk but it is not installable or
                                             openjdk-11-jdk but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But openjdk-8 and openjdk-11 are too old that I can't install them by using "sudo apt install".

so I install openjdk-8 manually, and also use `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` or `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade` ..., but still can't fix the problem.

The jave version now is:

```
$ java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
openjdk version "1.8.0_382"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.72.0.17-CA-linux64) (build 1.8.0_382-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.72.0.17-CA-linux64) (build 25.382-b05, mixed mode)
```

What else can I try?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you out. The crucial thing for me was that aptitude was willing to suggest downgrading packages whereas apt was not.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude

sudo aptitude install package-name
```

`aptitude` will suggest dependencies resolution for you e.g:

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Keep the following packages at their current version:

1. `libyaml-dev` [Not Installed]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/? (n)

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Downgrade the following packages:

1. `libyaml-0-2 [0.1.4-3ubuntu3.1 (now) -> 0.1.4-3ubuntu3 (trusty)]`

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] (Y)

If that doesn't work, you can also try:

```
sudo apt install -f package name
```

Will download missing folders.

Comment: Hi James, Thank you for the answer.
A while ago, I switched to using gcloud's native installation package for installation, and this problem was solved.
Using apt-get install gcloud may cause problems when installing other components.